# How do you reference a file on an external drive on a mac from a script command?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, path

If this is what I want in PC land
 F:\new\home\dir

What is the equivalent on a Mac?  I just see the external drive called untitled.  What is its path for a script command please?

Comment: This question most likely belongs in the think different forum instead.

Comment: Are you trying to create directories in this path? Are you trying to change the user home directory? Are you just trying to navigate to this path in the command prompt? As it is worded currently, it is difficult to tell what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @VirtualHat Assuming OP is just trying to navigate to the path, it is likely on-topic here because Macs are also PCs. It's a bit of a grey area frankly. As the question is clarified it may become more apparent whether or not it belongs one place or another.

Answer (score 3):

The mount points are under `/Volumes`. This includes the startup disk, which is a link back to `/`. Therefore if the removable disk shows up in Finder as "Untitled", you'll probably find it at

```
/Volumes/Untitled
```

Here's what the contents of my /Volumes looks like when I have an unnamed flash drive connected.

```
$ ls -la /Volumes
total 40
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root       wheel   204 27 Mar 23:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  41 root       wheel  1462 22 Mar 22:17 ..
drwxrwxrwx@  1 grgarside  staff  8192 22 Aug  2016 Untitled
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root       wheel     1 21 Mar 14:17 Mac SSD -> /
drwxrwxrwx   0 root       wheel     0 27 Mar 23:34 MobileBackups
```